# Unicode that is not recognized properly

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, unicode, flex4.5, flex4.6

I'm using in Unicode in my application using

```
for(var i:int=0;i<16;i++) {
  for(var j:int=0;j<16;j++) {
    button = new Button();
    button.x = j*35+10;
    button.y = i*20+10;
    button.height = 21;
    button.width = 35;
    button.setStyle("borderColor","red");
    button.setStyle(" fontWeight","bold");
    button.label= String.fromCharCode(0x2190+16*i+j);
    button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,greekalpha_clickHandler);
    vgr.addElement(button);
  }
}
```

But when I run this code, some symbols are recognized properly and others are not[image]

Hilighted words are recognized properly and others are not. What mistakes have I made in this code?

Comment: What happens to the other symbols? This could be just a font issue, since those those that you indicate as working are probably supported by far more fonts than the rest.

Comment: exactly, have you tried with proper unicode font? not embedded.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela other symbols not properly visiable.

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela yes i've tried with standard unicodes.

Comment: It is font issue, I've tested your code and: ⊂,⊃,⊄ this is a copy of trace output, in the ouput panel it displays as squares, but when I've pasted to the skype (which I have set to use Arial Unicode MS) then hte chars revealed, also as you can see in the comment they display correctly.

Comment: actually character all revealed properly but some character display in very poor quality...

Comment: Embed the Fonts, Use `Lucida Sans Unicode` and also set the `advancedAntiAliasing = true; `

Answer (score 0):

(I'm just reposting the apparent answer to get this question off the unanswered list. The original answerer(s) in the comments are more than welcome to post instead. I also know the given answer should work, based on my own experience.)

In order to ensure the Unicode symbols show up properly, you need to embed a Unicode font, such as Arial Unicode MS or Lucida Sans Unicode, and set your text objects to that font (it doesn't happen automatically).

Then, turn on anti-aliasing, either via `advancedAntiAliasing = true;` or by setting the Anti-alias property in Flash Professional to "Anti-Alias for readability".

Any issues beyond this, I presume, are device-specific.

Comment: Thanks Mr.@jasanMc92,Let me check and will update u soon